# KeyError: Index(['song_id'], dtype='object')

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wrote the following script in Python:

```py
#Read userid-songid-listen_count triplets
#This step might take time to download data from external sources
triplets_file = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Pak Abdul DSS/Netflix_Dataset_Ratings.txt'
songs_metadata_file = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Pak Abdul DSS/Netflix_Dataset_Movie.csv'

song_df_1 = pandas.read_table(triplets_file,header=None)
song_df_1.columns = ['song_id','user_id','listen_count']

#Read song  metadata
song_df_2 =  pandas.read_csv(songs_metadata_file)

#Merge the two dataframes above to create input dataframe for recommender systems
song_df = pandas.merge(song_df_1, song_df_2.drop_duplicates(['song_id']), on="song_id", how="left")
```

This is a sample dataset I used:

- [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTUgK.png)
- [Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gHP0.png)

And this is the `KeyError` I got:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-82f0753d9b34> in <module>()
     11 
     12 #Merge the two dataframes above to create input dataframe for recommender systems
---> 13 song_df = pandas.merge(song_df_1, song_df_2.drop_duplicates(['song_id']), on="song_id", how="inner")

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in duplicated(self, subset, keep)
   6195         diff = Index(subset).difference(self.columns)
   6196         if not diff.empty:
-> 6197             raise KeyError(diff)
   6198 
   6199         vals = (col.values for name, col in self.items() if name in subset)
KeyError: Index(['song_id'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Hey @Ocha, could you provide your sample dataset as text (not images)? That way others can reproduce your code more easily.

Comment: Hey @BeniTrainor. Thank you, this is my dataset look :                                      
 song_id user_id  listen_count year  title
175  2024881 2 1992 Reservoir Dogs
175  2030809 2 1992 Reservoir Dogs
175  2031565 2 1992 Reservoir Dogs

Comment: sorry, i cant edited my question

Comment: Ocha, you should also include a sample of the contents of the song metadata file. As it stands, it's not possible to reproduce your Error and give you feedback.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> *I'm resorting to "psychic debugging" because the question is missing critical data. In future, please try to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).*
>
> *You probably weren't able to edit your question earlier because there was a pending suggested edit. You should be able to edit it now.*

The problem appears to be that `song_df_2` (*Netflix_Dataset_Movie.csv*) is missing the "song_id" column.

You can check which columns `song_df_2` has using `print(song_df_2.columns)`. Since you are using `read_csv()` without specifying the `header` parameter, it will infer the column names from the first line in the CSV file. Make sure that line is correct. If you can't spot the problem, edit your question to include the first couple of lines of *Netflix_Dataset_Movie.csv* (and also *Netflix_Dataset_Ratings.txt*). Insert ```` ``` ```` before and after each snippet to preserve line breaks.

I suspect the issue is that the file *Netflix_Dataset_Movie.csv* is tab-delimited rather than comma-delimited (tab-delimited files must be read using `pandas.read_table()` rather than `pandas.read_csv()`). Make sure you download the file from Google Sheets as a CSV.